# How to add a downloadable PDF file to a middleman-generated website?

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, download, middleman

I am using Middleman to create a static website. I would like to offer the possibility of downloading a PDF file.

Where should I place the PDF file so that I can use link_to helper methods and so that it is automaticaly included in the build ?

Do you have any suggestions ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the answer myself.

Middleman will build and deploy exactly what is placed in the "source" folder unless there is a need of compilation.

That means that you can create a "resources" directory, in the source "folder" and link from your web pages to that directory and whatever you put in it. However, I did not managed to use the "link_to" helper. So you have to know the relative path to your resources and specify it in full.

Bonus : add a .htaccess file in your resources directory containing the line :

```
AddType application/octet-stream .pdf
```

to make sure your PDF file will be downloaded.

Hope that helps ! :-)